# Mongodb read locks

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with custom _id and 500M+ documents. Size of the _id's index is ≈25Gb and whole collection is ≈125 Gb. Server has 96 Gb RAM. Read activity is only range queries by _id. Explain() shows that queries use the index. Mongo works rather fast some time after load tests start and slows down after a while. I can see in a log a lot of entries like this:

*[conn116] getmore csdb.archive query: { _id: { $gt: 2812719756651008, $lt: 2812720361451008 } } cursorid:444942282445272280 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 **numYields: 748 locks(micros) r:7885031** nreturned:40302 reslen:1047872 **10329ms***

A piece of db.currentOp():

```
"waitingForLock" : false,
                        "numYields" : 193,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(869051),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                                },
                                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(1369404),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                                }
                        }
```

What is locks(micros) r? What can I do to cut it down?

Answer (score 8):

> What is `locks(micros) r`?

The amount of time that **read locks was held** (in microseconds).

- `R` - Global read lock
- `W` - Global write lock
- `r` - Database specific read lock
- `w` - Database specific write lock

---

> What can I do to cut it down?

- [How does sharding affect concurrency?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-does-sharding-affect-concurrency)

  > Sharding improves concurrency by distributing collections over multiple `mongod` instances, allowing shard servers (i.e. `mongos` processes) to perform any number of operations concurrently to the various downstream `mongod` instances.
- [Diagnosing Performance Issues (Locks)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/#locks)

  > MongoDB uses a locking system to ensure data set consistency. However, if certain operations are long-running, or a queue forms, performance will slow as requests and operations wait for the lock. Lock-related slowdowns can be intermittent. To see if the lock has been affecting your performance, look to the data in the `globalLock` section of the `serverStatus` output. If `globalLock.currentQueue.total` is consistently high, then there is a chance that a large number of requests are waiting for a lock. This indicates a possible concurrency issue that may be affecting performance.
  >
  > If `globalLock.totalTime` is high relative to uptime, the database has existed in a lock state for a significant amount of time. If `globalLock.ratio` is also high, MongoDB has likely been processing a large number of long running queries. Long queries are often the result of a number of factors: ineffective use of indexes, non-optimal schema design, poor query structure, system architecture issues, or insufficient RAM resulting in page faults and disk reads.
- [How We Scale MongoDB](http://blog.mongohq.com/how-we-scale-mongodb/) (Vertically)

  > Sadly, MongoDB itself will usually become a bottleneck before the capacity of a server is exhausted. Write lock is almost always the biggest problem (though there are practical limits to how much IO capacity a single MongoDB process can take advantage of).

Comment: Thank you, Wahyu! Yes, of course, I need sharding. But I think I do something wrong. Maybe my _id. It doesn't grow monotonically. BTW, why does it work so bad with 96 Gb of RAM? Of course, I can add more servers, but I'll have much more intensive load in production. About 10 times more intensive. So I want to achieve satisfactory performance on single machine. Am I wrong? I use 6 separate Mysql servers now. It works bad, but works.