# How can I reduce time spent acquiring the mongodb schema lock?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a mongodb cluster, backed by WiredTiger, in production, with a 3 node replica set consisting of a master and two slaves.  One of the slaves has another service co-located that queries the slave extensively.  In addressing some slowness in the co-located service I'm seeing a lot of surprisingly slow queries.  This one took 3.3 seconds:

```
  find: "myColl",
  filter: { myField: "myValue" },
  projection: { name: 1 },
  $db: "myDb",
  $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1568198047, 3), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } },
  lsid: { id: UUID("2ed823aa-e6af-4898-a4c1-c039d28a32ab") },
  $readPreference: { mode: "secondary" } }
  planSummary: IXSCAN { myField: 1 } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:232
  locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } },
          Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } },
          Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } }
  storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 355, timeReadingMicros: 4 }, timeWaitingMicros: { schemaLock: 3284692 }
```

The line that stands out to me here, is the last one, indicating that it spends 99.9% of its time waiting to acquire something called a schema lock.

I checked this particular database and collection and it turns out the collection had 50 items at query time.  Furthermore, there's also an index on `myField`.

Why is a read query waiting to acquire a schema lock?  What can I do to eliminate this long wait?

Comment: what is  your mongodb  version

Comment: We're running mongodb version 4.0.10

Comment: `Time in microseconds that the operation (if modifying the schema) had to wait to acquire a schema lock.`

Comment: it  shows  you have  modifying  schema !  what  about  your  query .

Comment: The query is (buried, I suppose) in the OP. It's just a `find` with this filter: `{ myField: "myValue" }`.  Not something I'd expect to be modifying the schema.  As I mentioned we don't have any schema validation rules on this particular collection either.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this topic a while ago, and in my case there were not much tuning I could do on MongoDB, all the indexes were there and I optimized how I was querying the DB.

The way I debugged I first got all DB stats to get a clear overview of the locks and concurrencies:

```
> db.serverStatus().globalLock
{
    "totalTime" : <num>,
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : <num>,
        "readers" : <num>,
        "writers" : <num>
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : <num>,
        "readers" : <num>,
        "writers" : <num>
    }
}

> db.serverStatus().locks
{
    <type> : {
        "acquireCount" : {
        <mode> : NumberLong(<num>),
        ...
    },
    "acquireWaitCount" : {
        <mode> : NumberLong(<num>),
        ...
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        <mode> : NumberLong(<num>),
        ...
    },
    "deadlockCount" : {
        <mode> : NumberLong(<num>),
        ...
    }
}
```

If you have studio3t it is way easier to analyze the stats and get some vizualisation.

if your system is not yet using the wiredTiger you may consider it: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/

> WiredTiger uses document-level concurrency control for write
>   operations. As a result, multiple clients can modify different
>   documents of a collection at the same time. For most read and write
>   operations, WiredTiger uses optimistic concurrency control. WiredTiger
>   uses only intent locks at the global, database and collection levels.
>   When the storage engine detects conflicts between two operations, one
>   will incur a write conflict causing MongoDB to transparently retry
>   that operation.

In our case we increased some of the batch sizes in some requests that didn't need such a fast response and removed some of the indexes which in our case with inser had an impact.

Answer (score -1):

You might face this problem due to concurrency. I believe write operations take time as MongoDB doesn't allow multi collection operations.

You can check this previous issue on read locks in MongoDB.

[Mongodb read locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893432/mongodb-read-locks)

Also, you can get details on locks under server status, check the queue when the query is fired.

db.serverStatus()